# Counting the occurrence of two words at the beginning of a text file

Tags: python

I am withing a python code to read all lines in a text file (b.txt) and count those with special words (ATOM and HETATM) at the beginning of each line. The b.txt file is as follows:

```
REMARK 480  ATOM      ZERO OCCUPANCY
ATOM   3332  CA  GLY A   8       9.207   4.845  44.955  1.00 42.92           C  
HETATM 2954  O   HOH A 489     -17.507   4.101   8.012  1.00 53.13           O
```

and the code is:

```
pdb_text = open("b.txt","r")
data = pdb_text.read()
n_atoms = data.count("ATOM")
n_het_atom = data.count("HETATM")
total_atoms = n_atoms + n_het_atom
print('Number of atoms:', total_atoms)
```

I expect “2” as the output, but I get “3” instead.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, the problem is in the first line. How can I make the code read the words (ATOM and HETATM) if they only appear at the beginning of the file (indexes 0-5)?

Answer (score 0):

For counting the lines that start with `ATOM` or `HETATM` you can use `string`'s `startwith` function. For example you can do:

```
data = ""
with open("b.txt","r") as file:
    data = file.readlines()

counter = 0
for line in data.split('\n'):
    if line.startswith("ATOM") or line.startswith("HETATM"):
        counter = counter + 1

print('Number of atoms:', counter)
```

Comment: No need to call it twice.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following code, you can read a PDB file and count the number of atoms in it.

```
# open the pdb file
pdb_file = input ("Enter the name of your PDB file: ")
pdb_text = open(pdb_file,"r")
# read contents of the pdb file to string
data = ""
data = pdb_text.read()
# get number of occurrences of ATOMS and in the pdb file
n_atoms = 0
for line in data.split('\n'):
    if line.startswith("ATOM") or line.startswith("HETATM"):
        n_atoms = n_atoms + 1
print('Number of atoms:', n_atoms)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's generalize it:
We want a function which takes a file_path and a list of words.
It should then return a dictionary of the line counts starting with the words.
For the sum, we takes the values of the dictionary and sum it. We can take that also as a function.

In other languages, such a function which returns a dictionary of the words with their count as value `frequence`. Since we count not overall occurrence but those at the start of the lines, we call it `start_frequencies`:

```
def start_frequencies(path, words):
    dct = {}
    with open(path) as f:
        for line in f:
            for word in words:
                if line.startswith(word):
                    dct[word] = dct.get(word, 0) + 1
    return dct
```

The magic is `dct.get(word, 0)` because it says: "If the word exist in the dictionary `dct` already as a key, take the value of it, else take as default value (the count) `0`."

Then, we can write the function which returns the sum of all start counts:

```
def sum_of_start_frequencies(path, words):
    dct = start_frequencies(path, words)
    return sum(dct.values())
```

So in your case, you use it like:

```
pdb_file = input ("Enter the name of your PDB file: ")
sum_of_start_frequencies(pdb_file, ["ATOM", "HETATM"])
```

It should return 2.